# I'm having problems checking if class exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The blow script works but is also outputting a "type e" error in jquery...

I've been looking at this for about 20mins now and am failing to see the problem.

```
if ($('input[type="submit"]').hasClass('.grey-button')) {
        $(this).wrap('<span class="button grey-button"></span>');
    } else {
        $(this).wrap('<span class="button"></span>');
    }
```

What am i mssing ?

Comment: `hasClass('.grey-button')` should be `hasClass('grey-button')` without `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to use `.classname` in `hasClass()`. just call with classname without dot eg `hasClass('classname');`

just use

```
$('input[type="submit"]').hasClass('grey-button')
```

Comment: urgh... thanks, been working for 12 days straight now. Think I need a break!

Answer (score 1):

Checking with [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) doesn't require to pass selector (the dot):

```
.hasClass('grey-button')//just use class name
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the class we doesn't not need . with the selector. changed it as below

```
.hasClass('grey-button')
```